# Polymer with Node and MySQL not recognizing JSON

Tags: node.js, polymer

I'm using Node and MySQL for the backend and Polymer for front end, and I cannot get Polymer to render a JSON array.

**Node/MySQL Code**

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'root',
    database : 'test'
});
connection.connect();



 connection.query('SELECT * FROM ACTIVITY', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
    return;
  }
  json = JSON.stringify(rows);
  console.log(json);
});

connection.end();
```

**Polymer Frontend**

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Activity Selection">
  <iron-ajax 
    id="getActivity"
    auto
    url="scripts/dbcon.js"
    handle-as="json"
    on-response="handleResponse"
    last-response="{{ajaxResponse}}">
  </iron-ajax>
  <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content">
    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[ajaxResponse]]">
      <paper-item><b>{{item.ACTIVITY_NAME}}</b></paper-item>
    </template>
  </paper-listbox>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

**JSON Output**

```
[{"ID":1,"ACTIVITY_NAME":"Coffee"},{"ID":2,"ACTIVITY_NAME":"Gym"},{"ID":3,"ACTIVITY_NAME":"Lunch"},{"ID":4,"ACTIVITY_NAME":"Vending Machine"},{"ID":5,"ACTIVITY_NAME":"Pool"}]
```

When I run this command: `node dbcon.js`, the output from `console.log` is the JSON array shown above.

For some reason, Polymer isn't recognizing the JSON array. In the Chrome DevTools console, there were no errors/outputs.

In another test scenario (which is working), I manually copied the JSON array output into a file, changed the `url` parameter from `"scripts/dbcon.js"` to `"scripts/test.json"`, and reloaded the electron app; and Polymer was able to display the JSON content in the dropdown list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`<iron-ajax>.url`](https://beta.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-ajax/iron-ajax#property-url) property is intended to specify the URL target of the request. It does not execute the response as JavaScript (like a `<script>` tag would), which seems to be what you're expecting.

In your case, the `<iron-ajax>` is reading the contents of `scripts/dbcon.js` and attempting to parse it as JSON (because of `handle-as="json"`). The parsing fails, resulting in a `null` response value.

To fix this, you should set `<iron-ajax>.url` to the URL of your Node server that is providing the JSON response.

Comment: *continued edit

Thanks for the input and information. Right now I am not using a server is it still possible to extract the query result convert to json with json.stringify then get the actual json data to be passed/parsed?

In the future I may be deploying this on to an actual server.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What query are you talking about? Are you asking whether `<iron-ajax>` could parse JSON?

Comment: In the node portion

I have connection.query('SELECT * FROM..') and yea if iron-ajax could parse the returned json query.

Comment: Yes. It seems you've already confirmed that (without realizing it). Your original question indicates the JSON output of `JSON.stringify()`, which confirms that you *can* stringify the results of the query. And your test that changes the `url` to `scripts/test.json` confirms that `<iron-ajax>` *can* parse JSON.